# Are there any barriers to telomere sequencing other than length?

Tags: dna-sequencing, eukaryotic-cells, telomere

In the comments to an answer [on this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/98638/52598), it was noted that long read sequencing methods (e.g., from PacBio or Oxford Nanopore) have largely eliminated repeat-based assembly problems for bacteria. This [paper on centromeres](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2013-14-1-r10) suggests that this is nearly the case for those sequences as well.

Telomeres, however, can be much longer, [up to 50kb for humans](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/telomeres-of-human-chromosomes-21041/). Read length is thus obviously still a barrier for telomere sequencing, even with the best current technologies.

My question, however, is this: are there any other barriers besides read length? Telomeres also have other modifications, such as their loop structure, and are famously subject to degradation. Do these or other issues also pose barriers to sequencing, or are they readily dealt with in normal protocols?